# Update shapefile data source with wildcard using python

Tags: python, arcmap, shapefile

I am attempting to update a layer's data source in Arcmap using python

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
    if lyr.name == "project_whl":
        lyr.replaceDataSource("F:\\Jobs2012\\05665\\EPASS\\", "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE","1205992_whl")
```

This WORKS!

HOWEVER I would like to use a wildcard instead of explicitly stating the dataset_name

Example below:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
        if lyr.name == "project_whl":
            lyr.replaceDataSource("F:\\Jobs2012\\05665\\EPASS\\", "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE","*whl")
```

Yet does not work, I have tried *, ?, %, _, & none of these work...

Just get the following error message

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Layer: Unexpected error
```

Your thoughts, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah - I wouldn't expect any sort of wildcard specification to work due to the risk of returning multiple possible candidate shapefile datasources.  I think you'll have to add a function to get the shapefile name via the Python OS namespace.
Something like this should work:

```
def getFileName(dir):
 import os
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
  for f in files:
   if "shp" in f:
    return f.replace('.shp','')

# And then you're loop will look like this:
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
 if lyr.name == "project_whl":
  myFile = getFileName("SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE")
  lyr.replaceDataSource("F:\\Jobs2012\\05665\\EPASS\\", "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE",myFile)
```

Note that this method will return the first shapefile encountered in SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this.

Credit goes to user blah238 for suggesting using os.path.splitext

```
import os
import arcpy

# Function to remove ".shp" from shapefile
def delExt (shpFile):
    nPath = os.path.splitext(shpFile)
    return nPath[0]

# Update files with correct data source
os.chdir(ePassPath)
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith("_whl.shp"):
        whlPath = files
    elif files.endswith("_aoa.shp"):
        aoaPath = files
    elif files.endswith("_ws.shp"):
        wsPath = files
    elif files.endswith("_route.shp"):
        routePath = files

#=== Loop throught layers find the one to be replaced ===

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
     if lyr.name == "project_whl":
        lyr.replaceDataSource(ePassPath, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE",delExt(whlPath))
    if lyr.name == "project_aoa":
        lyr.replaceDataSource(ePassPath, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE",delExt(aoaPath))
    if lyr.name == "project_ws":
        lyr.replaceDataSource(ePassPath, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE",delExt(wsPath))
    if lyr.name == "project_route":
        lyr.replaceDataSource(ePassPath, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE",delExt(routePath))
```

Comment: Better to use [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) than string slicing for removing the file extension IMO!

Comment: Sorry, Valvelondon did not think of you as was already using os in my code.                                                            for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith("_whl.shp"):
        whlPath = files

Comment: I did not include it before as did not feel it was related to my question on wildcards within replaceDataSource. However, credit goes to you for confirming was on the right track.

Comment: Fair enough. we can delete this thread then.

Comment: Would it not be more useful to share our results with the community?

Answer (score 1):

In general, unless the documentation says something should work, don't expect it to. :)

Here's what the [Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) documentation has on the `dataset_name` parameter:

> A string that represents the name of the dataset the way it appears in the new workspace (not the name of the layer in the TOC). If `dataset_name` is not provided, the `replaceDataSource` method will attempt to replace the dataset by finding a table with a the same name as the layer's current dataset property."

So you might try leaving it blank if you want it to locate it based on the previous dataset name.

Comment: Thanks, did try leaving blank still gave me error. Also will try implementing os.path.splittext.